# Wordpress: custom template containing form and query of custom table

Tags: php, forms, templates, wordpress

Wordpress 4.4.2 Theme= Meeta from WPZoom

I have created a custom template that contains an SQL query of a custom table of dogs. The query works fine via the WPDB Class and I can display the output data in an acceptable format.

Now in the same custom template I insert a php form to allow the user to enter search criteria.

The form displays ok but the query executes immediately without waiting for the user to hit submit, consequently I cannot enter any search criteria. What should I do to hold the query until the form has been submitted?

I have fiddled around with this for some time and many times if I introduce an error elsewhere display reverts to home page without displaying errors. Do I have to turn on error display or is this sent to a log somewhere.

```
        <?php the_content(); ?>
                //=================================
                <?php

                function test_input($data) {
                $data = trim($data);
                $data = stripslashes($data);
                $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                return $data;
                }

                // set variables to wildcard
                $dog_name = "%";
                ?>

                <h2>Chercher dans la base</h2>
                 <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

                 Dog_name: <input type="text" dog_name="dog_name" value="<?php echo $dog_name;?>">

                 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

                </form>

                <?php
                $dog_name = test_input($_POST["dog_name"]);

                global $wpdb;

                $query = "SELECT offspring.dog_name, offspring.sex, offspring.color, offspring.dob, offspring.cotation, offspring.titles, offspring.hd, offspring.titles, offspring.eyes, offspring.dna, offspring.born_in, offspring.prod_prop, sire.dog_name AS sire, dam.dog_name AS lice 
                    FROM BP_dog AS offspring 
                    JOIN BP_dog AS sire ON sire.dog_id = offspring.sire_id 
                    JOIN BP_dog AS dam ON dam.dog_id = offspring.dam_id
                    ORDER BY dog_name";
                word                       
                   $results = $wpdb->get_results($query);

                   $num_rows = $wpdb->num_rows;
                   print  "Number of rows = $num_rows.<br>";

                    foreach ($wpdb->get_results($query)as $row) {
                    print $row->dog_name . "\t";
                    print $row->sex . "\t";
                    print $row->dob . "\t";
                    print $row->color . "\t";
                    print $row->cotation . "\t";
                    print $row->titles . "\t";
                    print $row->hd . "\t";
                    print $row->eyes . "\t";
                    print $row->dna . "\t";
                    print $row->born_in . "<br>";
                    print "Sire = " . $row->sire . "\t";
                    print "Lice = " . $row->lice . "<br>";
                    print $row->prod_prop . "<br><br>";
                   }
                   ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Query you have written will directly runs if the page is loaded/reloaded. Use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)  to execute code only id you `$_POST` data.

```
<h2>Chercher dans la base</h2>
<form method="post" action="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=4">
Dog_name: <input type="text" name="dog_name" value="<?php echo $dog_name;?>">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST["dog_name"])) {
function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}   
$dog_name = test_input($_POST["dog_name"]);

global $wpdb;

$query = "SELECT offspring.dog_name, offspring.sex, offspring.color, offspring.dob, offspring.cotation, offspring.titles, offspring.hd, offspring.titles, offspring.eyes, offspring.dna, offspring.born_in, offspring.prod_prop, sire.dog_name AS sire, dam.dog_name AS lice 
    FROM BP_dog AS offspring 
    JOIN BP_dog AS sire ON sire.dog_id = offspring.sire_id 
    JOIN BP_dog AS dam ON dam.dog_id = offspring.dam_id
    ORDER BY dog_name";

   $results = $wpdb->get_results($query);

   $num_rows = $wpdb->num_rows;
    foreach ($wpdb->get_results($query)as $row) {
    print $row->dog_name . "\t";
    print $row->sex . "\t";
    print $row->dob . "\t";
    print $row->color . "\t";
    print $row->cotation . "\t";
    print $row->titles . "\t";
    print $row->hd . "\t";
    print $row->eyes . "\t";
    print $row->dna . "\t";
    print $row->born_in . "<br>";
    print "Sire = " . $row->sire . "\t";
    print "Lice = " . $row->lice . "<br>";
    print $row->prod_prop . "<br><br>";
   }
}
?>
```

I also modified few things on the code :

1. Removed "`word`" at line 46
2. Change `input type="text" dog_name="dog_name"` to `input type="text" name="dog_name"`
3. Removed `$dog_name = "%";`. Not sure why you are using this

Comment: Thanks very much Siva. I got the form to run correctly and execute the query thanks to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I made a more "hands-on" query builder that gonna work with any custom form to any table.

```
 public function getResults() {
    $params = [];
    
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
      if(!empty($value)) {
        array_push($params, [$key => $value]);
      }
    }
    
    $query_sufix = " WHERE ";
    
    for($i = 0; $i < count($params); $i++) {
      foreach ($params[$i] as $key => $value) {
        if($i == 0) {
          $query_sufix .= $key." = ".$value;
        } else {
          $query_sufix .= " AND ".$key." = ".$value;
        }
      }
    }
    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM {your-table}";
    
    if(!empty($params)) {
      $query .= $query_sufix;
    }
    
     $rows = $wpdb->get_results($query);
     return $rows;
    }
```